# kube-prometheus-stack upgrade failed with errors: "failed calling webhook x509: certificate signed by unknown authority" and "field is immutable"

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-node-exporter, kube-state-metrics

I just upgraded `kube-prometheus-stack` using Helm chart on my Kubernetes cluster using Terraform and started seeing the following 2 errors:

#### Error 1:

```bash
failed calling webhook "prometheusrulemutate.monitoring.coreos.com": 
failed to call webhook: 
Post "https://kube-prometheus-stack-operator.infra.svc:443/admission-prometheusrules/mutate?timeout=30s": 
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

#### Error 2:

```bash
Error: cannot patch "kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-node-exporter" with kind DaemonSet: 
DaemonSet.apps "kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-node-exporter" is invalid: spec.selector: 
Invalid value: v1.LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{"app.kubernetes.io/instance":"kube-prometheus-stack", "app.kubernetes.io/name":"prometheus-node-exporter"}, 
MatchExpressions:[]v1.LabelSelectorRequirement(nil)}: field is immutable && 
cannot patch "kube-prometheus-stack-kube-state-metrics" with kind Deployment: 
Deployment.apps "kube-prometheus-stack-kube-state-metrics" is invalid: spec.selector: 
Invalid value: v1.LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{"app.kubernetes.io/instance":"kube-prometheus-stack", "app.kubernetes.io/name":"kube-state-metrics"}, 
MatchExpressions:[]v1.LabelSelectorRequirement(nil)}: field is immutable
```

You can find the upgrade path to see both older and newer versions of image and chart of Kube Prometheus Stack in the table below:

| Component | Old Version (Dated: 14 April, 2021) | New Version (Dated: 24 July, 2023) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Image | v0.46.0 | v0.66.0 |
| Chart | 14.9.0 | 48.2.0 |

**How to fix those 2 errors?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Fix for Error 1:

To fix the 1st error, I changed the `prometheusOperator` configuration to set `failurePolicy` to `Ignore` under `admissionWebhooks` in the default values file for Helm chart as follows:

```
prometheusOperator:
  enabled: true
  admissionWebhooks:
"Fail"
    failurePolicy: "Ignore"
```

#### Fix for Error 2:

To fix the 2nd error, I disabled both `kubeStateMetrics` and `nodeExporter` configuration in the default values file for Helm chart by setting `enabled` to `false` and then applied the Helm chart and then enabled both by setting `enabled` to `true` and then applied the Helm chart and that worked. Maybe, deletion of resources was required for a successful installation in the newer version. Not sure what caused that. Maybe some incorrect configuration in the default values file during upgrade.

Reference: [kube-prometheus-stack / v48.2.0](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack/48.2.0)